# How to get Dialler Call Option "Viber, Skype" on Android 4.4.2 with Samsung Galaxy S5

Tags: settings, phone-app, skype, viber-messenger

At the dialer screen I do not receive the option to call using regular number, Skype or Viber.

How can I fix this so that I'm prompted when I want to make a call?

Any suggestion would help me a lot.

Best wishes,
Martin

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution. In the contacts, tapping twice on the picture by a specific contact opens up the option to contact the person via all available means.

Answer (score 0):

You might have set the default dialing option in the past. Go to `Settings > Apps`, from `Options` select `Reset App Preferences`. But this will reset all the defaults you have set for the dialer and all other apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Sky Dialer for Skype](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nimeshm.skydialer) App, It lets you make Skype calls to your android contacts without merging the contacts with Skype (It requires the Skype app to be installed to work), lets you mark and organize favorites for easy calling too.

Full Disclosure: I am the app's developer